# how to make an admin panel for a ready database using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-admin

I have a ready database in MySQL, I want to have an admin panel using Laravel or PHP, is there any fast method to do it? 
I know this could be done in Python and Django, I tried it but I have some limitation in my VPS, so I need to do it in Laravel. 
if it could be done using Laravel, how much control do I have to customize this admin panel? like internationalization, or custom design?

any suggestion will be helpful thank you

```
Sorry, I haven't any code to show, I just need a recommendation.
```

Comment: use package like CRUD generator.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following tips.

1. take a look at laravel nova and/or laravel backpack
2. laravel can utilize multiple db connections

If it were me trying to get an admin panel up in a hurry, I'd use backpack and I'd setup the laravel basic user scaffolding in a separate db.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial and u can make admin panel whit in laravel and and customize controller how you want them to handle your functions http://connorleech.info/blog/Build-a-quick-admin-panel-in-Laravel-5/ still works in 5.7